# Use Overpass API to Extract data from OSM within a bbox

Tags: openstreetmap, geometry, overpass-api

I'm trying to extract only some data via Overpass API inside of specific box (By Coordinates).when i use this code via Overpass I'm getting

Overpass Query:

```
(
  way[landuse](40.0627513928,-2.1478584892,40.0845316612,-2.1151342638);
  node(w);
);
out body;
>;
out geom(40.0627513928,-2.1478584892,40.0845316612,-2.1151342638);
```

Result via overpass :

[image]

wanted result :
[image]

How do I keep only the data inside of the box which is defined by coordinates?

Comment: What exactly is the result you get and what is the one you want? Please use clear words, not images to specify that. To me the image looks like you get the data that intersects the rectangle so I am not sure what is wrong (if that is the bbox and the data, you didn't say).

Comment: i edited my question, sorry if it was not clear, i just need to remove parts out of my bbox, basecly the operation is like splitting osm data via bbox i'm not sure if it is possible ?

Comment: Cheers! I think what you are looking for is "clipping" the result features to the boundary of the bounding box and from what I know that is not possible via Overpass. You would need to do that using another service or local software once you have the data. I am not 100% sure so I will leave this as a comment, not an authorative answer.

Comment: This is explained in the Overpass docs under https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#out: A bounding box in the format "(south,west,north,east)" (normally used with the geom verbosity type). In this case, only elements whose coordinates are inside this bounding box are produced. For way segments, the first or last coordinates outside this bounding box are also produced to allow for properly formed segments (this restriction has no effect on derived elements without any geometry).

Comment: thanks guys for the quick reply, i also tried  "_ out body; " but I'm getting the same result.. any idea if there is some lib with c# to clip/split osm files ?